# Meaning of にある時? (「死にそうな目にあった時...」

Tags: grammar, verbs

I found this sentence:

> 死にそうな目にあった時、すぐに入りなおさないと。

I know what it means, but I can't understand the grammar behind "にあった時".

Answer (score 6):

[目に[遭]{あ}う](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%9B%AE%E3%81%AB%E3%81%82%E3%81%86) (not **ある**) is a set phrase meaning "to suffer/go through/'meet with' a bad experience".

The 目 is often preceded by negative descriptions (esp. adjectives) such as ひどい・苦しい・不快な, etc.  In this case, it's just 死にそうな.

The 時 is inconsequential here; just a normal "when ～".